# Multiply all even indexed integers by two

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, fixnum

Wanting to take a fixnum of integers and multiply all even(indexed) integers by two. I figured the best way to do this is first turn fixnum into an array. So lets say the following number of 16 digits: a = 4408041234567901

I know I could:

```
a.to_s.split('')
```

Which will return 'a' to an array of 'stringed' numbers. But then I cant follow up with:

```
a.map!.with_index {|i,n| i.even? n*2}
```

Guess I'm kinda stuck on how to create a method to do this. So my question may even be how to turn that group of numbers into an array of fixnums/integers instead of strings.

Comment: It sounds to me that you want to multiply the even-indexed digits of an integer by two. There's no such thing as a "fixnum of integers". Integers have digits, not other integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change it to an Array, you could do

```
a = 4408041234567901
arr = a.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
# => [4, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1]
```

You can also multiply alternate numbers by 2

```
arr = a.to_s.chars.map.with_index {|n,i| i.even? ? n.to_i * 2 : n.to_i }
# => [8, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 9, 0, 1]
```

Improving a little bit, you can use a `Hash` to find the number to be multiplied.

```
h = {true => 2, false => 1}
a.to_s.each_char.map.with_index {|n,i| n.to_i * h[i.even?]}
```

**EDIT**

I can explain each step, But it will be better if you can try to figure it out on your own. Open irb, type `a.to_s` and check the output. Then type `a.to_s.chars` and inspect the output and so on..

Comment: Could you explain exactly what is happening from converting 'a' to a string, then using chars, then 'map'ing it? I am kinda new and want to make sure I understand it all instead of just copy past you know?

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to remove the conditional altogether from the loop, by creating an `Enumerator` that contains the coefficients you want to multiply by (2 for even indexes and 1 for odd.)

```
coef = [2, 1].cycle
```

This essentially creates an `Enumerator` that alternately returns `2` and `1` when `next` is called on it. You can then use this to simplify your `map` to:

```
a.to_s.each_char.map { |v| v.to_i * coef.next }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 4408041234567901

even_odd = [:even, :odd].cycle
   #=> #<Enumerator: [:even, :odd]:cycle>
```

If the indexing starts with the highest-order (leftmost) digit:

```
a.to_s.each_char.map { |d|
  (even_odd.next == :even) ? 2*d.to_i : d.to_i }
  #=> [8, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 9, 0, 1]
```

If the indexing starts with the ones digit:

```
s = a.to_s
even_odd.next if s.size.even?
s.each_char.map { |d| ( even_odd.next == :even) ? 2*d.to_i : d.to_i }
  #=> [4, 8, 0, 16, 0, 8, 1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 18, 0, 2]
```

Here are the steps for the example when zero-based indexing starts with the highest-order digit.

[Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) converts the array `[:even, :odd]` to an enumerator:

```
even_odd = [:even, :odd].cycle
even_odd.next #=> :even
even_odd.next #=> :odd
even_odd.next #=> :even
even_odd.next #=> :odd
...

b = a.to_s
  #=> "4408041234567901" 
enum0 = b.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "4408041234567901":each_char>
```

The enumerator `enum0` passes the digits of `b` to `map`. I could have instead written:

```
b = a.to_s.chars
  # => ["4", "4", "0", "8", "0", "4", "1", "2",
  #     "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "0", "1"]
```

but that creates an intermediate array. The enumerator does not and therefore is more efficient. Continuing...

```
enum1 = enum0.map     
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "4408041234567901":each_char>:map>
```

You can think of this as a "compound enumerator". We can see its contents by converting it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> ["4", "4", "0", "8", "0", "4", "1", "2",
  #    "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "0", "1"]
```

The method `each` will pass each element of the enumerator into the block. Proof:

```
enum1.each { |d| (enum.next == :even) ? 2*d.to_i : d.to_i }
  # => [8, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 10, 6, 14, 9, 0, 1]
```

We can manually step through the elements of `enum1` by using [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). We will assign the value to the block variable `d` and perform the calculation in the block to map the digit `d`:

```
d = enum1.next
  #=> "4" 
(enum.next == :even) ? 2*d.to_i : d.to_i
  #=> (:even == :even) ? 2*"4".to_i : "4".to_i
  #=> (true) ? 8 : 4
  #=> 8 ("4" is mapped to 8)

d = enum1.next
  #=> "4" 
(enum.next == :even) ? 2*d.to_i : d.to_i
  #=> (:odd == :even) ? 2*"4".to_i : "4".to_i
  #=> (false) ? 8 : 4
  #=> 4 ("4" is mapped to 4)

d = enum1.next
  #=> "0" 
  #=> (:even == :even) ? 2*"0".to_i : "0".to_i
  #=> (true) ? 0 : 0
  #=> 8 ("0" is mapped to 0)
```

and so on.

Comment: This seems a little more foreign to me. I'm not sure why you used reverse and I need to study up on the next you called on the enum. Thank you for answer though!

Comment: Sorry, `reverse` was an artifact from some changes I made. I showed how the cycling enumerator is used. I prefer it to using `each_with_index` or `with_index`.